# Need the width of each element to be equal to the element's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple results chart.  I'm currently using the click function to test, but ideally I want it to load in with the width of each `.chart` class element being equal to the element's value. However, I can't seem to get it to work correctly. 
 This is the furthest I've gotten with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/wvjj4466/5/

```
$(".chart").click(function () {
    $(this).width($(this).attr("value"))
});
```

At first I thought it was something with tables, so I did try and got it working with just divs(https://jsfiddle.net/kph9uny9/5/) but it doesn't seem to transfer.

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
 $( this ).width($( this ).attr( "value" ))
 tag
```

Is this possible to do this with a table. If so, how? I've tried using this, each(), this.element, and a couple others things, but nothing is working.  I'm new to JQ/JS so any help is greatly appreciated. 
 Thanks!

Comment: Try `$( this ).width( $( this ).val() );`

Comment: Have a `div` element inside `td` and set its width

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `display: inline-block;` to td.chart in the css.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qsktrxd/1/)

JSFiddle also includes the code to make the bars the correct width on load.

Comment: @Squish No problem!